# Wierd NoSuchMethodError for URLEncodedUtils.format

Tags: java, apache, servlets

I am having a call to URLBuilder.build which has this call trace:

Servlet.service() for servlet authv0 threw exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.encodeQuery(URIBuilder.java:176) [httpclient-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]
    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.buildString(URIBuilder.java:140) [httpclient-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]
    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.build(URIBuilder.java:103) [httpclient-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]
```

I see this even has been there since [4.2](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#format%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and still it gives me a `NoSuchMethodError`. The jar version that is used is 4.2.5 as you see. Can someone point to what I am missing?

Here is my manifest file from 4.2.5 jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: oleg
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_22
Implementation-Build: tags/4.2.5/httpclient@r1469939; 2013-04-19 18:29
 :05+0200
Implementation-Title: HttpComponents HttpClient
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache
Implementation-Version: 4.2.5
Specification-Title: HttpComponents HttpClient
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Specification-Version: 4.2.5
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.5
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.5
url: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is almost always a problem with versions, whether multiple versions of the same jar in the classpath, or compiling with one version and running with another ... Sometimes these lines of code can tell you if a class is coming from some place you don't expect: `ClassLoader loader = URLEncodedUtils.class.getClassLoader();`  `logger.info(loader.getResource(“org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.class”);`

Comment: I am perplexed since I get this message in the log that clearly says the jar name. [httpclient-4.2.5.jar:4.2.5]